# Finding smallest substring not present in string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring

I have a string consisting only of digits 0-9. The string can be between 1 and 1,000,000 characters in length. I need to find the smallest number that isn't present in the string, in linear time. Here are some examples:

```
1023456789       //Smallest number not in string is 11
1023479          //Smallest number not in string is 5
112131405678910  //Smallest number not in string is 15
```

With size of 1,000,000, I figured that the smallest number not present in the string has to be at most 6 digits.

My approach was to generate all numbers 0 through 999,999 and insert them all in a vector (in order). Then make a map that marks what strings have already been seen. Then I iterate through the string, and for each position I get all substring starting from it, size 1 to 6, and I mark all those substrings as true in the map. At the end, I just check all keys one by one, and when I find the first one that has a false value in the map, I print it.

Here are some code snippets:

```
string tmp="0";
string numbers[999999];

void increase(int pos)
{
    if(pos==-1)tmp.insert(0,"1");
    else if(tmp.at(pos)!='9')tmp.at(pos)++;
    else
    {
        tmp.at(pos)='0';
        increase(pos-1);
    }
}

//And later inside main
for(int j=0;j<999999;j++)
{
    numbers[j]=tmp;
    increase(tmp.size()-1);
}
```

---

```
for(int j=0;j<input.size();j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<6;k++)
        {
            string temp="";
            if(j+k<input.size())
            {
                temp+=input.at(j+k);
                appeared[temp]=true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
int counter=0;
while(appeared[numbers[counter]])counter++;
cout<<numbers[counter]<<endl;
```

A note about the first part of the algorithm. I generate the vector once, then I use it for 100 strings. I need to parse all 100 strings in less than 4 seconds.

This algorithm is too slow for me as it is currently. Could I optimize some of the code, or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: Why are you using a vector?

Comment: Do you really need to store your test numbers anywhere?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Changed it to an array now. I was first testing another approach, then forgot to change it.

Comment: @t8h7gu Not really. But how could I then parse the map in order, starting from the smallest number?

Comment: @A.Andevski, do you mean linear time in relation to the length of the string or in relation to the number of substrings (which is quadratic in relation to the length of the string)? I'm not sure if the former is possible.

Comment: @user2079303 Let's say that I could use any algorithm faster than mine.

Comment: This sounds like a question from a competition -- please link to it so that we know it's not current.  I can think of an algorithm that is linear in the number of characters in the input plus the value of the answer.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing how you came up with 170,000.

Comment: The solution I came up with runs in O(nlog(n)); however, it has a horrid space efficiency. If I can optimize it further I'll contribute my thoughts.

Comment: @JacobPollack: If your solution is O(nlog(n)) time then it's necessarily also O(nlog(n)) space, which sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: I see. 170,000 is just 1,000,000/6 (roughly rounded). That's probably low. Consider, for example, that the string `"123456123"` contains four 6-digit numbers in just nine digits. It's probably possible to come up with an arrangement that comes very close to that compression ratio. I suspect your maximum is closer to 500,000.

Comment: @JimMischel: see de Bruijn sequences; for any alphabet of size k and any integer n, you can construct a cycle of size k^n which contains all k^n n-character sequences. Unwrapping the cycle produces a string of length k^n+n-1 whose first and last n-1 characters are identical. A 1,000,000-digit sequence has only 999,995 6-digit subsequences, so there are at least five six-digit subsequences not present. In particular, a de Bruijn sequence (cut rather than unwrapped) would have precisely that number of unique subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to build a tree of numbers that were met:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node() : count( 0 ) {}
    // create a tree from substring [from, to[ interval
    void build( const std::string &str, size_t from, size_t to )
    {
        Node *node = this;
        while( from != to )
            node = node->insert( str[from++] );
    }

    std::string smallestNumber(  bool root = true, int limit = 0 ) const;

 private:
    Node *insert( char c ) 
    {
        int idx = c - '0';
        if( !children[idx] ) {
            ++count;
            children[idx].reset( new Node );
        }
        return children[idx].get();
    }

    int count;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> children[10];

};

std::string Node::smallestNumber( bool root, int limit ) const
{
    std::string rez;
    if( count < 10 ) { // for this node string is one symbol length
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
            if( !children[i] ) return std::string( 1, '0' + i );
        throw std::sruntime_error( "should not happen!" );
    }
    if( limit ) { 
        if( --limit == 1 ) return rez; // we cannot make string length 1
    }
    char digit = '0';
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        if( root && i == 0 ) continue;
        std::string tmp = children[i]->smallestNumber( false, limit );
        if( !tmp.empty() ) {
            rez = tmp;
            digit = '0' + i;
            limit = rez.length();
            if( limit == 1 ) break;
        }
    }
    return digit + rez;
}

void calculate( const std::string &str )
{
    Node root;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ) {
        root.build( str, i, i + std::min( 6UL, str.length() - i ) );
    }
    std::cout << "smallest number is:" << root.smallestNumber() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    calculate( "1023456789" );
    calculate( "1023479" );
    calculate( "112131405678910" );
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: after some thought I realized that inner loop is completely unnecessary. 1 loop is enough. String length is limited to 6, I rely on OPs estimation of biggest number possible.

Output:

```
smallest number is:11
smallest number is:5
smallest number is:15
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach the problem. The idea is to generate sets of unique substrings of particular length, starting from the shortest and then testing those before generating longer substrings. This allows the code to not make assumptions about the upper bound of the result and also should be much faster for long input strings that have small results. Still, it's not necessarily better in the worst case of big results.

```
int find_shortest_subnumber(std::string str) {
    static int starts[10] = {
        0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 
        100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000
    };
    // can't find substrings longer than 9 (won't fit in int)
    int limit = std::min((int)str.size(), 9);
    for(int length = 1; length <= limit; length++) {
        std::set<std::string> uniques; // unique substrings of current length
        for(int i = 0; i <= (int)str.size() - length; i++) {
            auto start = str.begin() + i;
            uniques.emplace(start, start + length);
        }
        for(int i = starts[length - 1]; i < starts[length]; i++) {
            if(uniques.find(std::to_string(i)) == uniques.end())
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found (empty string or too big result)
}
```

I haven't done proper complexity analysis. I crudely tested the function with a particular test string that was `1 028 880` characters long and had the result of `190 000`. It took about 2s to execute on my machine (which includes generation of the test string which should be negligible).

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for the string in linear time (and space). Once you have the suffix tree, you simply need to breadth-first walk it scanning the children of each node in lexicographical order, and checking all 10 digits at each node. The first missing one is the last digit in the smallest missing number.

Since a 1,000,000 digit sequence only has 999,995 six-digit subsequences, there must be at least five six-digit subsequences not present, so the breadth-first search must terminate no later than the sixth level; consequently, it is also linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to know whether a number has been seen yet or not, it's probably easiest to use a `std::vector<bool>` to store that indication. As you walk through the input number, you mark numbers as true in the array. When you're done, you walk through the array, and print out the index of the first item that's still false.

Comment: I'll need to convert every single substring into a integer all the time. Won't that take me longer?

Comment: In such a small string I would say the time needed for type casting is not a factor, but the only way to check it is implementing and doing the benchmark. But I'd use an array, not a vector.

Comment: @user3564091: A vector is typically backed by an array, and `vector<bool>` has some (infamous) optimizations for packing data into less space.

Comment: OK, but this time it's not about packing it into less space, but accessing it quickly, and these two subjects are usually contradictory, but correct me if I miss something here.

Comment: @user3564091: Unless the array would be *quite* small (specifically, small enough to fit in cache), `vector<bool>` is mostly about trading extra CPU time to save memory access time. You can use a lot of CPU time to save only a few memory accesses and still come out ahead.

Comment: But what is the difference here between array and vector that would make the latter save memory access time? Also, do I understand correctly that according to what you say if the array and the vector would both be 'quite' small it doesn't make a difference which one of them is used in terms of efficiency?

Comment: @user3564091: The difference isn't between arrays and vectors *in general*. The difference is that the C++ standard specifies a specialization for `vector<bool>` in which each bool is stored as a single bit. When stored in an array, each `bool` is stored as an actual `bool` object, which has to be at least 8 bits and is often 32 bits.

Comment: Wow, you've just confirmed that I really should get C++ standard, thanks. But does this fact (i.e. storing bools as a single bit) does matter that much in terms of efficiency if both array and vector would be sufficiently small, i.e. fit in a cache etc.?

Comment: @user3564091: That depends. If you don't need anything else in the cache at the same time, then it probably won't make a big difference. If you need other data in the cache as well, it can start to make more difference.